# Accessing Android System Service from Libcore Class

Tags: java, android

I am working on a research project to look at malware and how to prevent it on Android. I am modifying the OS to allow my system service to record any app's attempt to access a file and report that up to a system service which will decide to grant access. I have the system service running on Android 7.1 and but I can't call the service manager which is in the android.os package in frameworks and the class I want to call from is in the java.io package in libcore-ojluni. I have the modification in java.io.FileOutputStream.java.

When I try to compile Android it gives me the error: "Package android.os does not exist"

I am thinking of using sockets to communicate to the service but that seems to slow as I would like a response before allowing access, and I don't want the process to hang.

Is there a way to include the package that I need? Is that even a good idea?

I haven't tried native services. I wanted to ask here before I try that. Is communicating up the Android OS Stack not doable?

Comment: This question is a little abstract. How exactly you're trying to bind the service? It doesn't even have to be a modified ROM, but it's enough to sign off the package with OS release keys.

Comment: I followed the example [here](https://blog.csdn.net/lewif/article/details/50687290) in the java half. I am using the context.getSystemService function to get the manager class that has the binding to the service. As seen in step 7 of the java half.

Comment: If package `android.os` does not exist, there is something fundamentally wrong(and it is still unclear where you even add that code). Native services are probably useless for this use case, because this all runs inside a JVM. Signing the ROM with the same key as the APK package makes it a system app, with signature protection level. only `@UnsupportedAppUsage` limits the usage.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a similar project, the goal was to prevent any application in the device to extract user files from the device without permission to do so.
Therefore, I tried to create a System Service (just like you) that should be called by the Libcore layer whenever an application is trying to read a user file.

However you cannot do that, given the fact that Android has a stacked architecture and lower layers cannot interact with upper ones. It makes sense that a general Java use case class such as FileOutputStream should not know about any Android specific class.

The solution I found was to create a new set of classes in the Libcore layer, instead of creating a system service. That way you can interact directly with core components like the IoBridge class and prevent reads / writes to files according to your specific conditions. You can even read the full byte content if you want to.

But if you really need it as a System service, I guess the only solution would be to completely change the way applications can access the file system. For example, a system service that would receive read / write requests, and then proceed to interact with the general classes in the Libcore layer. This would of course bring several challenges, because a single service would need to handle all the requests from all applications in the device. This way, the Libcore package should not be available in the application SDK, only by interacting with this service could apps communicate with the File System.